# Trouble understanding stack segment register

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, memory-segmentation, stack-pointer

Segment registers are used to increase the range of addressable memory from 64K to 1M bytes. But, I have trouble understanding **stack segment register** (SS) because stack already has two other registers associated to it, **sp** and **bp**.

Suppose, I have set **SS** to **5000h** and then decided to initialize the stack by initializing **bp** and **sp** registers. Initially the stack should be empty. So, both of **sp** and **bp** should have same content initially. Can I initialize **sp** with any random address or Will I have some restriction?

For Example, is it ok to initialize **sp** with the address **7000h**

Comment: I think you might be confused about how the registers are used.  `sp` is the architectural stack pointer; it is what indicates what region of memory is used by the CPU as stack, and it changes when you use push, pop, call, return, receive interrupts, etc.  `bp` is just a general-purpose register that happens to be convenient for addressing objects on the stack, like arguments and local variables in a high-level language.  But you can use it for something totally different if you prefer, and it plays no role in determining where the stack actually is.

Comment: Sure, you can initialize `sp` with `7000h`.  Then the stack will start at address `5000h:7000h`, i.e. linear address `57000h`, and grow downward.  That will work fine so long as there is a reasonable amount of writable memory at that address, which won't cause problems if it is overwritten (e.g. there is no important code or data in that region of memory).  Whether you set `bp` the same is of no consequence to the machine.

Comment: @NateEldredge But `bp` stores base address of the stack? and `sp` stores address of top of stack?

Comment: No.  `sp` stores the "top" of the stack in the sense that that's where you push and pop things, but numerically it's really the bottom (lowest address) since the stack grows down.  The address in `bp` is not in any sense the "base" of the stack.  You might use it in a function for the base of a **stack frame**, i.e. a particular *region* of the stack used for this function's local data, but "base" here means "reference point" and not "lowest address".

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have in mind some mental model like "the stack is the region of memory between bp and sp" but that is not the case.  Again, `bp` has no stack-related special significance to the machine; only `sp` does.

Comment: @NateEldredge ok got something about `bp` register. But still a doubt regarding `sp` register. Should I make sure that content in `sp` is an address that lies in the stack segment? (i.e. in stack segment's 64K available memory)

Comment: @kumarp - other than the fact that using bp based addressing defaults to using the stack segment register (ss), it's just another register, not directly tied to the stack, unless a program chooses to use it that way. In some cases, the data segment and stack segment are the same, allowing bp to be used as a 4th register to address the data segment in addition to bx, si, and di.

Comment: @kumarp: `sp` *always* is used to address part of the 64 KiB pointed to by `ss`. Any value between 0 and FFFFh that you can write into the 16-bit `sp` register will be used as an offset into the 64 KiB segment the base of which is specified by `ss` times 16. (Don't use odd values for `sp` however, so the usable range is 0 to FFFEh.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In x86, the stack is a LastInFirstOut (LIFO) structure where the `SS` segment register marks the start and the stackpointer `SP` points directly above the free space on the stack. In memory, the free space is lower than the used space because the stack grows downward. It is this downward expansion that makes talking about the stackpointer as "the top of the stack" confusing because it is counterintuitive for the top to be at the bottom.
In x86-16, the stack can occupy at most 64KB or 65536 bytes. The `SP` register which is a 16-bit register can never address anything outside of this stack segment.

Now if your program initialization has these instructions:

```
mov  ax, 5000h
mov  ss, ax
mov  sp, 7000h
```

you are telling that the stack is going to be a chunk of 28672 (7000h) bytes starting at linear address 0005'0000h and ending at linear address 0005'6FFFh. At this point in your program you can say that "the stack is empty". And it would be a severe programming error to eg. `pop ax` while the `SS:SP` register pair has 5000h:7000h.

```
| 5000h (SS)                                                     | 6000h
|                                                                |
|<--------------------------------- 64KB ----------------------->|
|      This is the stack     |   This is not part of the stack   |
|                                                                |
|                            ^                                   |
| 0                          | SP=7000h                    65535 |
```

In order to place a new item on the stack (`push` / `call` / `int`), the stackpointer `SP` is lowered and then the new item is written at that address. For removal (`pop` / `ret` / `iret`) the item where `SP` points at is read and then `SP` is raised.

Let's see that in action:

```
  mov  cx, 6144
More:
  push cx
  loop More
```

Registerwise, only the stackpointer `SP` has changed.

```
| 5000h (SS)                                                     | 6000h
|                                                                |
|<--------------------------------- 64KB ----------------------->|
|      This is the stack     |   This is not part of the stack   |
|                xxxxxxxxxxxx                                    |
|                ^                                               |
| 0              | SP=4000h                                65535 |
```

Now removing two thirds of it:

```
  mov  cx, 4096
More:
  pop  ax
  loop More
```

Once again, registerwise only the stackpointer `SP` has changed.

```
| 5000h (SS)                                                     | 6000h
|                                                                |
|<--------------------------------- 64KB ----------------------->|
|      This is the stack     |   This is not part of the stack   |
|                        xxxx                                    |
|                        ^                                       |
| 0                      | SP=6000h                        65535 |
```

We can read/write the stack memory just like any other memory. However because of the segmented nature of memory, ordinarily we would need to use the `SS:` segment override:

```
mov  ax, [ss:6000h]

mov  bx, 6000h
mov  ax, [ss:bx]
```

Or we could just make `DS` refer to the stack segment:

```
mov  cx, 5000h
mov  ds, cx 

mov  ax, [6000h]

mov  bx, 6000h
mov  ax, [bx]
```

Here begins the strange case of `BP`. The designer has made it so that all memory referencing that relies on the `BP` register, will be relative to the stack segment by default. We can address data in the stack segment without having to specify a segment override or manipulating the `DS` segment register if we load the offset address in `BP`:

```
mov  bp, 6000h
mov  ax, [bp]
```

Other than this 'stickyness' to the stack segment, there's nothing special about `BP`.

Comment: If I initialize SP to 0000h, then stack can not hold any data right?. And then if I push data, what will happen?

Comment: @kumarp "then stack can not hold any data right?" On the contrary. With `SP=0` you will have setup a stack of the maximum size of 64KB. Your very first `push ax` will subtract 2 from the `SP` register (it will become 65534) and then store `AX` at the address 65534.